# Problems with control hardware/drivers on Ubuntu Studio 19.04

Tags: uefi, 19.04, ubuntu-studio

Since I installed Ubuntu studio 19.04 to a hard drive I am having various issues. I've figured it has something to do with secure boot so I cut Windows out of my life completely, cleared secure boot files from UEFI BIOS and reinstalled, and all was well for a short while.

But now after installing a few things (nothing that changes any drivers) it seems to boot and not allow Ubuntu to control drivers. So now I can't change my resolution and detect a second monitor. `xrandr` also doesn't detect anything other then the one resolution for example.

I installed software like teamviewer, wine, lutris, foobar, OBS, DesMuMe(NDS emulator). Any help understanding this would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded the package from the Ubuntu packages website and followed the install instructions.

[Ubuntu packages website](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/x11/ubuntustudio-default-settings)

It seems donwloading the default settings package fixed my problem. Thanks!